# How to calculate time worked for time values in the same column

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime, datediff

I have the following data where all the clock ins and clock outs are in the same column. Following are the areas that I have noticed the data going weird:

1. A person who clocks in, forgets to clock out and vice-a-versa
2. The data is spread over a large period of time (2-3 years).
3. There are duplicates of the same clock-in/clock-out.
4. A person can work with clockin-Clockout-Break-Clockin-Clockout values.
5. A person could start work at 10:00 P.M and end work at 8:00 A.M The next
   morning.

I have the following data for your consideration.  Please also look at the SQL Fiddle for this problem. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/726b4/1/0)
**EDIT: Added new data to SQLFiddle.**It only allows 8k characters. Sad.
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TempTable
    CREATE TABLE #TempTable (
        EmployeeName varchar(40),
        EmployeeID INT,
        PostEditPunchValue DATETIME,
        PunchDate DATETIME,
        FormatTime varchar(20),
    )

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable (EmployeeName,EmployeeID, PostEditPunchValue,PunchDate,FormatTime) VALUES 
('FNU, LNU M', '12345', '2007-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2007-01-01 00:00:00.000', '12:00 AM' ),
('FNU, LNU M', '12345', '2008-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2008-01-01 00:00:00.000', '12:00 AM' ),
('FNU, LNU M', '12345', '2007-01-02 15:30:00.000', '2007-01-02 00:00:00.000', ' 3:30 PM' ),
('FNU, LNU M', '12345', '2007-01-02 08:17:00.000', '2007-01-02 00:00:00.000', ' 8:17 AM' ),
('FNU, LNU M', '12345', '2007-01-02 08:17:00.000', '2007-01-02 00:00:00.000', ' 8:17 AM' ),
('FNU, LNU M', '12345', '2009-01-02 08:00:00.000', '2009-01-02 00:00:00.000', ' 8:00 AM' ),
('FNU, LNU M', '12345', '2009-01-02 16:25:00.000', '2009-01-02 00:00:00.000', ' 4:25 PM' ),
('FNU, LNU M', '12345', '2009-01-02 16:25:00.000', '2009-01-02 00:00:00.000', ' 4:25 PM' ),
('FNU, LNU M', '12345', '2007-01-03 00:00:00.000', '2007-01-03 00:00:00.000', '12:00 AM' ),
('FNU, LNU M', '12345', '2009-01-03 07:50:00.000', '2009-01-03 00:00:00.000', ' 7:50 AM' ),
('FNU, LNU M', '12345', '2009-01-03 07:50:00.000', '2009-01-03 00:00:00.000', ' 7:50 AM' ),
('FNU, LNU M', '12345', '2009-01-03 16:01:00.000', '2009-01-03 00:00:00.000', ' 4:01 PM' )
```

And below is the code that I came up with. It works ok as long as the hours are not > 8 but filters out some legit records too where a person might have worked 9-10 hours on a given shift. Can someone suggest whats wrong and what I need to do to fix it?

```
;WITH 
CTE2T AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeName, PostEditPunchValue from #TempTable
    WHERE PostEditPunchValue BETWEEN PostEditPunchValue AND DATEADD(HH,23,PostEditPunchValue) AND PostEditPunchValue <> PunchDate
    and EmployeeName = 'FNU, LNU M' 
),
CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT  
         T1.EmployeeName
        ,t1.PostEditPunchValue StartDate
        ,min(t2.PostEditPunchValue) EndDate
    FROM 
        CTE2T AS t1
        LEFT JOIN CTE2T AS t2 ON (t1.EmployeeName = t2.EmployeeName
                                  and  t1.PostEditPunchValue < t2.PostEditPunchValue)
    WHERE 
        t1.EmployeeName = 'FNU, LNU M' 
    group by
        t1.PostEditPunchValue
    ,   t1.EmployeeName
),
CTE2 AS
( 
    SELECT 
        EmployeeName, StartDate, EndDate,
        DATEDIFF(HH,StartDate,EndDate) 'Hours' 
    from 
        cte1 
    group by 
        EmployeeName, StartDate, EndDate
)
SELECT * FROM cte2 where Hours > 8 or Hours = 0
```

The output that I get (from the code) is as below:

```
EmployeeName                   StartDate             EndDate        Hours   Flag


ANDERSON, LETICIA G|    2007-01-02 08:17:00.000|    2007-01-02 15:30:00.000| 7| 
ANDERSON, LETICIA G|    2009-01-02 08:00:00.000|    2009-01-02 16:25:00.000| 8| 
ANDERSON, LETICIA G|    2009-01-03 07:50:00.000|    2009-01-03 16:01:00.000| 9| Y
```

Comment: Could you please give a brief description of what you are doing with the columns.  Typically in this type of table you would just see an EmployeeID, InDateTime, OutDateTime.  Specifically can you tell me what the last three columns intent is?

Comment: Please also include the expected outcome of running your query.  This will help identify the problem.

Comment: My bad. The PostEditPunchValue column has the inTime and the OutTime both. I know its a bad design, but thats what I inherited. I am posting the output that I see. But sometimes I get exceptions where PostEditPunchValue repeats on the "EndDate" in row n and then StartDate in Row n+1.

Comment: Would it be reliable to assume that duplicate punches represent a punch out in the absence of the employee punching out?

Comment: That is a good question and I think the answer would be a yes to that.